# Notification Doubts: When to @?

Tags: support, edits, comments, notifications

I'm never quite certain when an `@User` is required when commenting on an answer and was hoping that someone could point me in the direction of some rules indicating when the mention is required to notify a user who would otherwise not be notified.

I'm aware that if I comment on a question, the question-asker will **always** be notified.

But if I comment on an **answer** to a question (whether it be my own answer or another user's answer), will the **question-asker** be notified?

Currently, I err on the side of caution and always use the `@` when commenting on answers, but I feel that this may be unnecessary.

---

I'm also conscious of the fact that new users will be unaware that the `@` is required to notify a member of a response.

For example, if I comment on a question requesting more information, I find myself having to remember to periodically revisit the question in case I have missed a response from the question-asker who has either edited the question (and I haven't been notified), or has responded to my comment without an `@` (and I haven't been notified).

Am I missing some functionality of the site that solves this issue?

---

### Edit

Having read the answer provided and the information in the FAQ, I understand that the question asker is **not** automatically notified when comments are posted on an answer to their question.

However, there is one scenario that I am still unsure about:

- I post an answer to a question (Asker is notified that a new answer has been posted)
- Asker comments on the posted answer
- If I reply to the Asker's comment on my answer, are they automatically notified, or must I include a 'ping' `@` in my response?

Comment: The definitive [FAQ is here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: I tend to avoid using @ unless the comment section is very active and i want to make it very clear who i'm speaking at. If they care what's being said, they'll look, if not, they won't. :shrug:

Comment: @CodyGray Many thanks - evidently my initial search before posting this question was obviously not thorough enough...!

Comment: It’s hidden on the global Meta. You wouldn’t find it just by searching here. You have to know where to look.

Comment: You must use `@` in any comment that is not on their post(question/answer). So yes, you need `@` for your last scenario.

Comment: @Dylan That's not 100% correct... it is true when two or more people have commented on a post but not if the OP of the post responds when only one person has commented. Please see my answer or the FAQ Cody Gray posted for the full details.

Comment: "_I find myself having to remember to periodically revisit the question_" - My userscript [Stack Reminder](https://stackapps.com/questions/8163/stack-reminder-remind-yourself-about-posts) may help you manage this if you find yourself doing this often.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you remember your first statement

> I'm aware that if I comment on a question, the question-asker will always be notified

Instead as

> I'm aware that if I comment on a **post**, the **post author** will always be notified

Then you'll have an easier time. It's not about being the asker, it's about being the author of a post. You can't actually ping the asker on an answer unless they've acted on that answer (commented or edited).

For anyone else, you need to ping them specifically and you can only ping based on that specific post's activity.

If you're the post author, there's one other exception. If only one person has commented on your post, they'll be automatically pinged if you comment on your post, even if you don't ping them. This is specifically designed for that situation you mention about unknowing new users.

So, to clarify:

- User A writes a post (question or answer, doesn't matter)
- User B comments on that post (any number of comments).
- User A comments on their own post.

User B will be notified of User A's comments without a ping being necessary and, in fact, if user A pings User B in a comment response, the `@username` will be removed from the comment.

From the meta post linked just below:

> however if only you and the author have commented on the post so far, the @name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value.

For the more detailed nitty gritty, see the [MSE FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) linked in the comments.

---

<sub>A "post" is any question or answer.</sub>

Comment: For people not meaning what "post" means, both answers and questions are posts

Comment: Thank you for the information. Having read your answer and the FAQ, I understand that the question asker is **not** automatically notified when comments are posted on an answer to their question. There is one scenario that I am unclear about, and so I have updated my question.

Comment: @LeeMac That's pretty much covered in that "If you're the post author" section. **If** the OP comments on your answer and you reply **and** no one else has commented on the answer, then your comment reply will notify them automatically *but* that has nothing to do with them being the asker. If two or more people have commented on your answer, you have to @ reply to ping the one you want to ping.

Comment: @Catija Many thanks, that clarifies things.